# Get nearby latitude and longitude based on current location in servlet

Tags: java, html, sql, servlets

Actually i am getting the value of current latitude and longitude from android device . So based on the current location i have to send the nearby latitude and longitude . Please give me some suggestion so that i can use it in my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get nearby `Longitude & Latitude`  by entering `ZIP/Postal` Code :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
  {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.println("Please enter a postcode:");
    String postcode=reader.readLine();
    StringBuffer input=new StringBuffer();
    String data=null;
    String latLong=null;
    String link="http://maps.google.com/maps?q="+URLEncoder.encode(postcode, "UTF-8");
    URL url=new URL(link);
    HttpURLConnection connection=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
    if(connection.getResponseCode()==200)
    {
      System.out.println("Success");
      while((data=br.readLine())!=null)
        input.append(data);
    }
    int x=input.indexOf("lat:");
    int y=input.indexOf("}",x);
    latLong=input.substring(x,y);
    latLong=latLong.replaceAll("lat:","");
    latLong=latLong.replaceAll("lng:","");
    System.out.println(latLong);
    String[] array=latLong.split(",");
    System.out.println("Latitude: "+array[0]+" and Longitude: "+array[1]+" for "+an>+postcode);
  }
```

See [this](http://www.javaservletsjspweb.in/2012/09/java-program-to-get-latitude-longitude-points.html#.VCjfQ_mSzGA) tutorial.

Comment: user3145373 ツ:How to get current location latitude and longitude in java? with out passing any input. If possible please let me know.